# Conformal transformation and coordinate changes

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory, action

Let $(M,g)$ be a spacetime and $x^\mu$ some local coordinates. We consider a massless scalar field $\phi$ on this fixed spacetime:
\begin{align}
S[\phi]&=\int_Md^nx\sqrt{-g(x)}~g^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\phi(x)\partial_\nu\phi(x)\\
&=\int_Md^nx\sqrt{-g(x)}~g(\partial\phi,\partial\phi)(x)
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ are the fields. Note that the metric is not dynamical, it's a background metric. I'm explicitly writing each dependence in the coordinates for later convenience. If we make the change of coordinates $x\to x(y)$, we have
\begin{align}
d^nx &= \left|\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right|^{n}d^ny \\
g^{\mu\nu}(x(y)) &= \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\beta}g^{\alpha\beta}(y)\\
\sqrt{-g(x(y))} &= \left|\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right|^{-n}\sqrt{-g'(y)}
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
S[\phi]&=\int_Md^nx\sqrt{-g(x)}~g(\partial\phi,\partial\phi)(x)\\
&= \int_Md^ny\sqrt{-g'(y)}~g(\partial\phi,\partial\phi)(x(y))
\end{align}
since the scalar product $g(\partial\phi,\partial\phi)$ doesn't depend on the chosen coordinates.

1. The action is therefore not invariant under arbitrary changes of coordinates, is that normal?
2. A change of coordinates implies a change of configuration too doesn't it ? Should I replace $\phi$ by $\phi'$, defined as $\phi'(y)=\phi(x(y))$?
3. In the particular case $g=\eta$ and $x=\Lambda y$, we see that this action is not Lorentz invariant, but where is the error?

Comment: What do you mean by "the action is not invariant under arbitrary changes of coordinates"? The value of $S[\phi]$ is independent of your chosen coordinates, and if you write it as you suggest in your second point, it really does take "the same form" in all coordinate systems. It can also be written in manifestly invariant coordinate-free notation as $\int_M \mathrm{d}\phi\wedge{\star\mathrm{d}\phi}$.

Comment: For me, the last expression of not exactly the same as the first expression. The simple substitution $x\longleftrightarrow y$ doesn't give te same expressions.